# Why is Pig reading only one register?

Tags: linux, apache-pig

..
Hello, everyone.

I just downloaded and extracted pig binaries.
I am having a weird problem when running pig in local mode as `pig -x local`.

I have a file which contains the following string: `hello,world,how,goes`.
Now, I try to load and display the contents with the next pair of grub
commands:

```
a = load 'file' using PigStorage(',') as (u:chararray, v:chararray);
illustrate a;
```

What I see in the table, however, is a single pair (hello, world), 
when I'm expecting two pairs (hello,world) and (how,goes).

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have separated file with delimiter comma (`,`). So, logically you will get that output. You will have to put double quotes around it. Something like this, `"hello,world","how,goes"` and then try and then you have put them in separate lines if you want two records. After that use `DUMP` command to see the output but not `illustrate` to see the output.

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work. I tried adding one record per line too. I think it may have something to do with mapper/reducer configuration, but I don't quite know what since I'm very new to MapReduce and Pig.

Comment: Yes, it just gives me the ("hello, world") tuple.

Comment: An update... it seems to work when I do a dump, so I probably misunderstood the usage of illustrate.

Comment: nice to help you. Edited answer accordingly :)